# Nested IF field in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, mergefield

I'm trying to create a word addin that adds complex IF Statement Creation, from a list of possible mergefields.

**Complex is**

`{ IF { = OR ( { COMPARE { MERGEFIELD Field_1 } <= "Value" }, { COMPARE { MERGEFIELD Field_2 } >= "Value" } ) } = 1 "True Instructions" "False Instructions" }`

Im trying to do this all in VBA, but im having issues with my Complex if, as I cant get the "}" to end in the right locations.

If I use the terminator "Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine" in any other location besides the end, it creates a mess and putts all the } at that line.

Here is my Code:

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="IF "


Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" = " & JointOperator1 & " ( "

'FIRST ARG
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:="COMPARE "


Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False, Text:="MERGEFIELD " & FirstArg1

    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=ComparisonType1
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(34) & SecondArg1 & Chr(34)


Selection.TypeText Text:=", "


'SECOND ARG
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
    Selection.TypeText Text:="COMPARE "


Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False, Text:="MERGEFIELD " & FirstArg2

    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=ComparisonType2
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(34) & SecondArg2 & Chr(34)


Selection.TypeText Text:=" ) "

Selection.TypeText Text:=" = 1 "

Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf & " " & Chr(34)


Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:=strTempIfTrue


Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(34) & " " & vbCrLf
Selection.TypeText Text:=" " & Chr(34)

Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:=strTempIfFalse


Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(34)
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

And this is what I get when generating the "Complex if"

```
{IF { = AND ( {COMPARE{MERGEFIELD FHB} = "T", { COMPARE {MERGEFIELD BLAH} = "F") = 1 "If True text" "If False Text"}}}}
```

**But it should be this:**

```
{IF { = AND ( {COMPARE{MERGEFIELD FHB} = "T" **}** , { COMPARE {MERGEFIELD BLAH} = "F" **}** ) **}**  = 1 "If True text" "If False Text"}
```

If someone could shed some light on this matter, where am I going wrong.
Or If there is a way of forcing the location of the Ending }, that would be great
I'm very new to VBA (I'm a C++ Programmer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem.

I used the word macro recorder(View>Macros>Record Macro...) to record me entering the complex if statement, then viewed the macro, by pressing Alt + F11 and selecting macros, and I simply replaced some strings with my variables.
and that has fixed the issues.

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone else, saving them hours of head scratching.

I had no Idea that you could record these actions to be reviewed later. You learn something new every day.

This is what the recording looked like.

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="IF "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:=" = AND ("
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:=" COMPARE "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="MERGEFIELD FHB"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
Selection.TypeText Text:=" = """""
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="T"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Selection.TypeText Text:=", "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="COMPARE "
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
    PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="MERGEFIELD Other"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
Selection.TypeText Text:=" <> """""
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="T"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Selection.TypeText Text:=")"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
Selection.TypeText Text:=" = 1 """""
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="IfTrue"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=" """""
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="IfFalse"
```